# How to stop jumping again when 3D character is in air (double jump)?

Tags: unity, c#, raycasting, jumping

I'm working on simple rpg and having some trouble with player jumping. I'm trying to use unity's raycast to check colliders under the player before jumping again. The problem appears that no matter how many tweaks I make to the distance or the validation of the canJump function, the raycast the player seems to at max jump twice. At lower levels the player can even hover if timed correctly. Could someone overlook my code since it appears that I might have a noob glitch somewhere?

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Player : MonoBehaviour
{

    public float speed;
    public float jumpForce;
    public float turningSpeed;

    private bool canJump;


    void Start()
    {

    }


    void Update()
    {

        RaycastHit hit;
        if (Physics.Raycast(transform.position, Vector3.down, out hit, 1.01f))
        {
            canJump = true;
        }

        ProcessInput();

    }


    void ProcessInput()
    {
        if (Input.GetKey("right") || Input.GetKey("d"))
        {
            transform.position += Vector3.right * speed * Time.deltaTime;

        }

        if (Input.GetKey("left") || Input.GetKey("a"))
        {
            transform.position += Vector3.left * speed * Time.deltaTime;

        }

        if (Input.GetKey("up") || Input.GetKey("w"))
        {
            transform.position += Vector3.forward * speed * Time.deltaTime;
        }

        if (Input.GetKey("down") || Input.GetKey("s"))
        {
            transform.position += Vector3.back * speed * Time.deltaTime;
        }

        if (Input.GetKeyDown("space") && canJump)
        {
            canJump = false;
            GetComponent<Rigidbody>().AddForce(0, jumpForce, 0);
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: Hint: the frame after I've left the ground, I'm still usually pretty close to the ground, so canJump gets set to true again. Where does it get set to false after that? ;)

Comment: Also, there are [gobs of existing answers here](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/search?q=unity+ground+check) and tutorials on the net containing working versions of this code. If you're having trouble reinventing the wheel, just use one that already works.

Comment: @DMGregory hmmm crap I thought it would be taken care of as the force itself would set you to false after you took off flying. 

Really? I have yet to see working versions of this code since it appears raycasting covers general  jumping and targeting since I am working on enemies next

Comment: Added a link to my comment above. Forces don't know about your boolean. Your jump code sets it to false the moment you jump, but the very next frame, the ray fires again, and if you haven't had a physics step in between to actually move you, you're still on the ground, so you immediately set it to true again.

Comment: Thanks for the hint since I would have never thought of that. I have been testing things for a few days though taking a step back I'm trying to understand the physical check that needs to be made that can confirm that the player is off the ground. At first I wanted to check against the jumping space between the ground and player but that turned out to be a dud since the jump space is too broad since jumping from a hill or a step can be very different. Next I wanted to check for a time delay between the player's original position between jumps but that didn't work out either.